# Using magento 2 only show review not rating in product page

Tags: magento2, review, ratings

I'm using Magento 2 and porto theme on the product page only show the product review. Rating option not displayed in the page.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to enable rating from admin,

```
Stores -> Attributes -> Rating
```

[image]
Click on Ratings

Now Select Price, Quality, Rating and Value,
Open Page from click on above,

**Set Your Store from Visibility.**

```
Set Is Active to checked.
```

Clear Cache.

Comment: your post is very useful thank you .. it working